# How can I run a UiPath process with a script?

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-line, rpa, uipath

I understand that it is possible to kick off a process in UiPath, using a powershell script. I do not have Orchestrator installed and would like to start the process without having to load up the workflow first.

Does anybody know how to do this? Or any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the process in powershell or in the command prompt.

UiPath made a guide for running a process with the command prompt:
https://www.uipath.com/kb-articles/start-process-from-command-line

**offline alternative to Orchestrator**

> *Please note:*
>   - this feature is not compatible with UiPath 8.0 or lower version
>   - this feature is not compatible with the Community Edition

if you are searching for an offline alternative to Orchestrator, you can use Windows task scheduler as described by UiPath 
https://www.uipath.com/kb-articles/how-to-schedule-a-task